# Query about immigration history

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration

I have been to the UK for almost 8 years. I got a baby born there. I was on a student visa and was not finding any mean to extend my stay. In the end, I put up a human rights case which was finally refused and I went through the judicial review which was also refused. Lastly, I left the UK voluntarily with my family at my own expense. At departure time when they handed over our passports, they got our signs on removal papers. My question is that if I or my wife now apply for any visa, are we under one year ban to re-enter the UK or not?

Comment: Possibly a two year automatic ban for you https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/673999/GGFR-Section-2-v29.0EXT.PDF#page30 depending on the exact circumstances. And potentially discretionary refusals on expiry of the entry ban. Why are you even thinking of trying to get back to the UK after all that? What are your citizenships? You’ll get better answers if you can supply more information

Comment: What did it say on the removal papers?